# SSIS Import Flat file to DB once then check if file name

Tags: sql, csv, import, ssis, dataflow

I have a SSIS package that imports a flat file into a table within a db then moves on to next data flow task. This works as expected.

After the initial loading file into db I want to check to see if the file name has changed.

If it has, delete the content of db table and re import flat file.
If it hasn't don't do anything and move onto next task.

Any advice around how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated

---

**Update**

What I thought I could do is to check a location.

If the file exists then delete content from db table and import file into DB table. Then delete the file.
If the file doesn't exist then don't import/don't delete file and don't delete the db table. Simply move onto next task.

Is there a tool that I can use to check if file exists? Is my solution achievable?

Comment: add delete trigger in the db table

Comment: did u tried FTP task to check if file exists

Comment: i thought about doing this... have a sql task to run select case when count(*) >0 then 'true' else 'false' end as 'count'
from dbo.Service
and then based on that result would determine wich path the data flow would go in? @Bhouse

Comment: or u can simply use IF @@rowcount > 0 ..TRUE else false

Comment: for the sql statement?

Comment: yes in sql statement

Comment: I enter in my sql statement on the sql task but it is unsuccessful I have a success arrow going to a task and a failure arrow going to another task in the understanding that if result matched query it would go one way else another. is this incorrect?